System crash when wifi is connected and ethernet cable gets plugged in
My xubuntu 24.04 thinkpad x270 consistently crashes when wifi is connected and an ethernet cable gets plugged in.
The system does not freeze completely, but get's unusable. For instance typing a command in the console is possible, but when hitting enter nothing happens. Even shut down won't complete.
From /var/log/syslog:
 kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: NIC Link is Up 10 Mbps Half Duplex, Flow Control: None
 kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: kworker/1:1/54/0x00000002
 kernel: Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg qrtr snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_ctl_led snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic bnep snd_sof_pci_intel_skl uvcvideo snd_sof_intel_hda_common videobuf2_vmalloc uvc videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 soundwire_intel snd_sof_intel_hda_mlink videodev btusb soundwire_cadence btrtl videobuf2_common btintel mc cdc_mbim btbcm btmtk snd_sof_intel_hda cdc_wdm cdc_acm snd_sof_pci bluetooth snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof ecdh_generic snd_sof_utils ecc soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_bus snd_soc_avs snd_soc_hda_codec snd_soc_skl snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_sst_ipc snd_soc_sst_dsp snd_soc_acpi_intel_match intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_soc_acpi intel_uncore_frequency intel_uncore_frequency_common snd_soc_core iwlmvm intel_pmc_core_pltdrv intel_pmc_core snd_compress intel_vsec ac97_bus binfmt_misc mac80211 pmt_telemetry pmt_class
 kernel:  snd_pcm_dmaengine libarc4 intel_tcc_cooling snd_hda_intel iwlwifi snd_intel_dspcfg x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_intel_sdw_acpi intel_powerclamp snd_hda_codec coretemp tps6598x think_lmi rapl ee1004 mei_pxp mei_hdcp typec nls_iso8859_1 intel_cstate intel_wmi_thunderbolt firmware_attributes_class wmi_bmof snd_hda_core cfg80211 i915 snd_hwdep snd_pcm i2c_i801 i2c_smbus intel_xhci_usb_role_switch snd_timer serial_multi_instantiate intel_pch_thermal mei_me drm_buddy mei ttm drm_display_helper thinkpad_acpi nvram cec rc_core i2c_algo_bit acpi_pad joydev input_leds mac_hid serio_raw msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport efi_pstore nfnetlink dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 dm_crypt cdc_ncm cdc_ether usbnet mii crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel sha256_ssse3 rtsx_pci_sdmmc sha1_ssse3 ahci psmouse intel_lpss_pci intel_lpss idma64 libahci xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas e1000e rtsx_pci snd soundcore video ledtrig_audio platform_profile wmi aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd
 kernel: CPU: 1 PID: 54 Comm: kworker/1:1 Not tainted 6.8.0-39-generic #39-Ubuntu
 kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 20HMS0Y71D/20HMS0Y71D, BIOS R0IET73W (1.51 ) 03/25/2024
 kernel: Workqueue: events e1000_watchdog_task [e1000e]
 kernel: Call Trace:
 kernel:  <TASK>
 kernel:  dump_stack_lvl+0x76/0xa0
 kernel:  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
 kernel:  __schedule_bug+0x64/0x80
 kernel:  schedule_debug.isra.0+0xdb/0x130
 kernel:  __schedule+0x69/0x6b0
 kernel:  ? kick_pool+0x7e/0x100
 kernel:  schedule+0x33/0x110
 kernel:  schedule_hrtimeout_range_clock+0xbc/0x150
 kernel:  ? __pfx_hrtimer_wakeup+0x10/0x10
 kernel:  schedule_hrtimeout_range+0x13/0x30
 kernel:  usleep_range_state+0x65/0xa0
 kernel:  e1000e_read_phy_reg_mdic+0x98/0x2a0 [e1000e]
 kernel:  e1000e_update_phy_stats+0x85/0x290 [e1000e]
 kernel:  e1000e_update_stats+0x4c9/0x4e0 [e1000e]
 kernel:  e1000_watchdog_task+0xf7/0xa80 [e1000e]
 kernel:  process_one_work+0x16c/0x350
 kernel:  worker_thread+0x306/0x440
 kernel:  ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0xe/0x20
 kernel:  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
 kernel:  kthread+0xef/0x120
 kernel:  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
 kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x44/0x70
 kernel:  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
 kernel:  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
 kernel:  </TASK>

uname -r: 6.8.0-39-generic
Apport is turned on, but no crash file get's created.
When I turn of wifi first and then plug the ethernet cable, it doesn't crash but works as it should.
Any idea what could fix this?

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

Thanks @waltinator. sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager does not produce anything when the ethernet cable gets plugged in, neither does service NetworkManager status show any change. What should I look for regarding service --status-all?
